# VBA to check for blank cells in columns based on value in another column

Tags: vba, excel

Given

```
O    1    2    3   A
A    4    5    6   B
B    7    8    9   D
     O             3
     C            15
     T            18
```

I'm looking for VBA code to validate that when column A contains a value that the remaining columns also contain values and when it doesn't contain a value, that columns 2 & 5 also contain values but 3 & 4 don't.

I've simplified the example, in a real sheet there will be many more columns and rows to check.

I've considered COUNTIF and INDEX/MATCH and array forumlas but from my understanding these all work on single columns at a time.

I want to do something like WHEN A1:An<>"" THEN COUNTBLANK(B:E) ELSE COUNTA (C:D)

Is the best way to use autofilter using blanks in A and then countblank and then a second autofilter for values in A.

Thanks

Comment: you really dont need vba for this. try `=IF(LEN(A1)>0,COUNTA(B1:E1)=4,AND(COUNTA(B1,E1)=2,COUNTA(C1:D1)=0))` copied down each row. It returns true if the row validates or false if not.

Comment: or for a one-shot formula that tells you if any row doesn't validate then try `=(COUNTIFS(A1:A4,"",B1:B4,"<>",E1:E4,"<>",C1:C4,"",D1:D4,"")+COUNTIFS(A1:A4,"<>",B1:B4,"<>",C1:C4,"<>",D1:D4,"<>",E1:E4,"<>"))=ROWS(A1:A4)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a couple of nested IF formulae as follows:

```
=IF(A1<>"",
    "A not empty, "&IF(COUNTBLANK(B1:E1)=0,
                       "B:E not blank",
                       "B:E have blanks"),
    "A blank, "&IF(AND(COUNTBLANK(B1)+COUNTBLANK(E1)=0,
                       COUNTBLANK(C1)+COUNTBLANK(D1)=2),
                   "Columns 2&5 have values and Columns 3&4 don't",
                   "but condition not met"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for going down the VBA route is that I want a generic reusable function as opposed to a formula I copy between cells and sheets changing the columns etc along the way ending up with a lot of duplicate code.

So something that takes a column to test and a value to test it with. Third parameter would be a range of columns to validate, and the fourth parameter the validation.

I don't want any solution to have the columns hard coded and I don't want intermediate totals at the end of rows. This is fairly easily achieved in Excel itself...

The reason for trying to use countblank is that I can apply it to a range.

After a lot of searching I discovered this (the columns don't match the original example)

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A19<>"")*(B2:D19=""))
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A19="")*(D2:D19=""))
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A19="")*(B2:C19<>""))
```

Nice huh? I just need to convert it into VBA now.

Thanks